# Why does it take less force to mate a full-detent SMPM connector than to demate?

Tags: rf, connector, coax

As seen in the table at the bottom of the [page](http://www.microwaves101.com/microwave-encyclopedia/804-smp-connectors) the mating force of a full-detent SMPM connector is less than its demating force.  This is the opposite of every other type of SMP/SMPM connector listed in the table.  Why is this?

Comment: link is broken for me

Comment: Also for me. But it's even broke if I go to the main microwaves101 page and try to click through to that entry.

Comment: that's probably a typo anyway

Comment: @VladimirCravero It's not a typo, that's what I thought when I first saw it.  I checked a few manufacturer's and they all have the demate force being larger than the mating force.

Comment: That's very interesting. Have a look at the answer below, I can't fully understand it because I can't understand some words but maybe it can help you

Comment: Another question: you are asking why as in "how is this possible" or why as in "why do we need it to be so"?

Comment: I have looked at various standards and could not find any good answer as to why insertion force is lower. I have withdrawn my answer as a result.

Comment: @VladimirCravero  The question as worded is asking "why", but an answer to the "how" question would also be enlightening.

Comment: I'm very curious right now, and it seems nobody can answer. Did you try to write an email to the manufacturer?

Comment: @VladimirCravero no, I haven't contacted any manufacturers

Comment: Well give it a try, they actually answer (usually)

Answer (score 1):

How is fairly simple.  By the principle of the inclined plane, they just use different slopes on each side of the catch, the shallower slope will require less force to displace the catch.